# Null pointer exception has occurred while setting the setText property of checkbox dynamically in android

Tags: android, checkbox

```
         try
         {
         LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
         CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(this.getApplicationContext()); 
         cb.setText("string");
         ll.addView(cb);
         this.setContentView(ll);
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
          Log.e("log_tag", "exception in setting chkbox value "+e.toString());
        }
```

I'm not getting the value to `checkbox` object/in set text property when debugging my code.

Comment: try changing the this.getApplicationContext() it seems he doesnt create the Checkbox

Comment: Log the exception stacktrace or remove the catch block altogether to learn exactly where it NPEs. If I'd have to guess it's because `ll` is null.

Comment: At which line you'r getting error?

Comment: yes ur guess is correct ll is null

Comment: Must check that your `LinearLayout` has a id of `linearlayout1`???

Comment: <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearlayout1" > yes the id is same

Comment: cant understand now what to do . .

Answer (score 0):

Try out this :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
    try {
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
    cb.setText("string");
    ll.addView(cb);
    // setContentView(ll);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag","exception in setting chkbox value " + e.toString());
    }

    }
```

**EDIT:**
This is the XML file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: whats that R.id.frame

Comment: It is the LinearLayout which you have used in your code like this :"LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);"    I just gave ID "R.id.frame" to my LinearLayout.

Comment: Still not getting the value

Comment: its not creating checkbox may be due to ll is null

Comment: I have tried above code.And its working fine. CheckBox displays properly without any exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting NullPointerException please add the log. If the checkbox is not visible please set the width and height of the cb after creating it.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams chkBoxParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  cb.setLayoutParams(chkBoxParams);
```